# Android - RTL layout becomes LTR after inflation

Tags: android, layout, view, android-actionbar, right-to-left

I have a custom `Action Bar` `XML` layout file in my `Android` project:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:textDirection="rtl">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:text="Some Text"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Now if try to load and display this `Action Bar` like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.id.custom_action_bar);
```

The layout gets loaded as `RTL` and text direction is `RTL`, and everything works fine, but I wanted to make the title dynamic so I decided to `inflate` the layout file into a `View`, and change the text of the `TextView` like this:

```
View customActionBar = LayoutInflater.from(this)
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_action_bar, null);
TextView actionBarTitle = customActionBar.findViewById(R.id.tv_name);
actionBarTitle.setText("Any Text");
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(customActionBar);
```

But then the layout and text direction become `LTR`. I tried to set the direction to `RTL` programmatically, and that didn't work too.

> **What is wrong here? What should I do to fix it?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `android:supportRtl="true"` in the AndroidManifest.xml to have rtl layout